# Desabilitar botão durante processamento javascript c#

Tags: javascript, c#

tenho o seguinte botão asp:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnOk" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" CausesValidation="true" ClientIDMode="Static"  Text="Ok" Width="80px" OnClick="btnOk_Click" OnClientClick="btnOk_OnClick();return true;" class="dxbButton_Glass dxbButtonHover_Glass"></asp:Button>
```

E o seguinte script:

```
function btnOk_OnClick() {
    $("#btnOk").prop("disabled", true);
}
```

O evento no servidor:

```
    protected void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         new Processar();
         ((Button)sender).Enabled = true;
    }
```

A idéia aqui é que o botão fique desabilitado, visto que o processar demora, mas quando eu desabilito o botão no java script, o click do botão não faz post, assim o evento btnOk_Click não é executado.

Tem alguma solução? 
Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Remova o evento cliente do botão (`OnClientClick`)

E use essa linha ao carregar a página:

```
window.onbeforeunload = btnOk_OnClick;
```

Comment: quem negativou a resposta poderia ao menos ter a educação de explicar o motivo.

Comment: Eu negativei, Ricardo. Pelo simples motivo da perda de navegabilidade - ou do uso desnecessário de recursos. Você vai forçar que o botão seja desabilitado mesmo quando o usuário trocar de página, por exemplo. Pode ser que funcione, mas nao achei uma boa solução e negativei.. Mas não sou o dono da verdade, o importante é o amigo Gabriel Reis ter o problema resolvido. EDIT: Vou tirar o negativo..acho que as respostas não devem ser julgadas por opiniões, mas sim por funcionalidades. Como resolve o problema em questão, vou retirar o `-1`.

Comment: Não tem problema o negativo, só acho que faltou explicar, para se tiver algum problema tentar não repetir. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução com `jQuery`:

1- Retirei o `OnClientClick`:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnOk" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" CausesValidation="true" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="Ok" Width="80px" OnClick="btnOk_Click" class="dxbButton_Glass dxbButtonHover_Glass"></asp:Button>
```

2- Criei um evento de captura ao submeter seu formulário:

```
$("#id_do_seu_form").submit(function() {
    //desabilita o botão
    $("#btnOk").prop("disabled", true);
});
```